# Delphi: Types other than Integer for indexing TStringList items

Tags: delphi, types, enums, tstringlist, tlist

`Arrays` can be indexed using user-defined enumerated types. For example:

```
type
  TIndexValue = (ZERO = 0, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR);

var
  MyArray: array[Low(TIndexValue) .. High(TIndexValue)] of String;
```

Elements from this array can then be referenced using `TIndexValue` values as an index:

```
MyArray[ZERO] := 'abc';
```

I am trying to obtain this same *general* functionality with a `TStringList`.

One simple solution is to cast every index value to an `Integer` type at the time of reference:

```
MyStringList[Integer(ZERO)] := 'abc';
```

Another solution (to hide all the casting) is to create a subclass of `TStringList` and defer all the casting to this subclass's subroutines that access the inherited `Strings` property:

```
type
  TIndexValue = (ZERO = 0, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR);

type
  TEIStringList = class(TStringList)
  private
    function GetString(ItemIndex: TIndexValue): String;
    procedure SetString(ItemIndex: TIndexValue; ItemValue: String);
  public
    property Strings[ItemIndex: TIndexValue]: String 
      read GetString write SetString; default;
  end;

function TEIStringList.GetString(ItemIndex: TIndexValue): String;
begin
  Result := inherited Strings[Integer(ItemIndex)];
end;

procedure TEIStringList.SetString(ItemIndex: TIndexValue; ItemValue: String);
begin
  inherited Strings[Integer(ItemIndex)] := ItemValue;
end;
```

This works fine for a single implementation that uses the enumerated type `TIndexValue`.

However, I would like to re-use this same logic or subclass for several different `TStringList` objects that are indexed by different enumerated types, without having to define `TStringList` subclasses for each possible enumerated type.

Is something like this possible? I suspect I may have to depend on Delphi's Generics, but I would be very interested to learn that there are simpler ways to achieve this.

Comment: Can you explain how `array [TIndexValue] of string` is deficient?

Comment: Are you asking why I'm choosing to use `TStringList` instead of a string array? I've written a few utility functions that depend on lists and not arrays, and I would like to keep their implementation the same

Comment: If you used a string list, what would be stopping you calling Add on it repeatedly and adding more items than you had indices?

Comment: Hah, good point. The creation of the lists are convenient using the enum values, but the code handling the lists can only reduce the number of elements.

Comment: Elements will not be repositioned in the list. The values are combined or eliminated, so the list structure is really only being used because of the utility functions it interfaces with

Comment: And I shouldn't have said "reduce the number of elements" in the previous comment. The values will be set to empty strings, but the location of the element will not change.

Comment: I'd use the array type from my first comment and make the helper methods receive open arra of string as their parameters.

Comment: do you really need `TStringList`? may be `TDictionary<TIndexValue, string>` is better?

Comment: also you can create descendant generic class like `TMyStringList<T : ordinal>` with `property MyItems[idx : T] : string read...` and then cast `T` to integer in get-method. but anyway if you only need container to store string and access it by your `TIndexValue` then `TDictionary` is better solution;

Comment: @teran: please read the previous comments. David Heffernan's suggestion using arrays is the most sensible and adaptable for my situation (i.e. lists with known maximum length)

Comment: @teran: As far as I know there is no generic restriction that limits T to ordinals only. `ordinal` does not work and even if it would - an Enum is not an ordinal; its values are

Comment: Look at the `array properties` topic in the fine manual. Virtually any type can be used as index! There is an flaw in your idea, though, Count loses sense and have always to be equal to High(TIndexOrdinal) - Low(TIndexOrdinal) + 1

Comment: @Chris, enumerated types are subset of ordinal types.

Comment: @user539484: the question was regarding `TStringList`, not `array`s. The `array` solution was already posted in the question. Chris was saying `T` is not necessarily an ordinal type, so the `Integer` casting is invalid.

Comment: @ardnew, i was telling you about array **properties**, not array **types**. In the second case type of index has to be ordinal, in the first one it has not. Look at TStrings.Values for example.

Comment: @David: I agree. I see no reason NOT to use `array[TIndexType] of string`. a TList<T>, TStringList, etc. has no advantages here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that generics would be by far the most elegant solution. Using them would be as simple as rewriting your class above as:

```
TEIStringList<T> = class(TStringList)
```

and then replacing all TIndexValue references with T. Then you could create it just as any other generic:

```
var
  SL: TEIStringList<TIndexValue>;
begin
  SL:=TEIStringList<TIndexValue>.Create;
  (...)
  ShowMessage(SL[ZERO])
  (...)
end;
```

If you insist on avoiding generics, maybe operator overloading would be of use. Something like the following should work:

```
type
  TIndexValueHolder = record
    Value : TIndexValue;
    class operator Implicit(A: TMyRecord): integer;
  end;

(...)

class operator TIndexValueHolder.Implicit(A: TMyRecord): integer;
begin
  Result:=Integer(A);
end;
```

Then use with:

```
var
  Inx : TIndexValueHolder;

begin
  Inx.Value:=ZERO;
  ShowMessage(SL[Inx]);
end
```

UPDATE:
You could adapt TIndexValueHolder for use in a for or while loop by adding Next, HasNext, etc. methods. This might end defeating the purpose, though. I'm still not sure what the purpose is, or why this would be useful, but here's some ideas for how to do it, anyways.

Comment: By the way, the downvote on the other answer almost discouraged me from making my own attempt at an answer. Is his answer so bad that you thought you should punish him for making an effort?

Comment: is that question for me? I wasn't the one who downvoted him. Thanks for your answer though

Comment: @ardnew Sorry, i assumed it was you. I still still think the downvote was out of place, though, unless the culprit comments with a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can use a class helper and declare the default property index as Variant:

```
type
  TEnum1 = (Zero = 0, One, Two, Three, Four);
  TEnum2 = (Nul = 0, Een, Twee, Drie, Vier);
  TEnum3 = (Gds = 0, Psajs, Oeroifd, Vsops, Wowid);

  TStringListHelper = class helper for TStringList
  private
    function GetString(Index: Variant): String;
    procedure SetString(Index: Variant; const Value: String);
  public
    property Strings[Index: Variant]: String read GetString write SetString;
      default;
  end;

function TStringListHelper.GetString(Index: Variant): String;
begin
  Result := inherited Strings[Index];
end;

procedure TStringListHelper.SetString(Index: Variant; const Value: String);
begin
  inherited Strings[Index] := Value;
end;
```

Testing code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Strings: TStringList;
begin
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Strings.Add('Line 1');
    Strings.Add('Second line');
    Strings[Zero] := 'First line';
    Memo1.Lines.Assign(Strings);
    Caption := Strings[Psajs];
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
end;
```

<sup>See edit history for a previous less successful attempt.</sup>

Comment: What would the advantage of class helpers be, compared to, say, simple inheritance or delegation, in this situation?

Comment: @Rudy It avoids the need for multiple derivatives. With this single helper, you handle all enumerations at one. Of course, the intermediate TEnumStringList isn't necessary (the helper could be for TStringList itself also), but this was inspired by OP himself.

Comment: @NGLN: With a derived class, you can do the same. I still don't see the need for a class helper.